# Splunk modular input update parameter

Tags: python, splunk

Is there a way to update an input parameter of an modular input script with Splunks Python SDK?

```
def stream_events(self, inputs, ew):
    twitter = OAuth1Session(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

    for input_name, input_item in inputs.inputs.iteritems():
        hashtag = input_item["hashtag"]
        since_id = input_item["since_id"]

        if since_id == "0":
            url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%%23%s" % hashtag
        else:
            url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?since_id=%s&q=%%23%s" % (since_id, hashtag)

        r = twitter.get(url)

        output = json.loads(r.content)
        if len(output["statuses"]) != 0:

            for tweet in output["statuses"]:
                print_xml_stream(input_name, json.dumps(tweet), tweet["created_at"])
```

I set the `since_id` parameter to 0, then I call the Twitter API for the first time. After I get the results I want to update the `since_id` parameter with the `max_id` field from Twitter search metadata (`output["search_metadata"]["max_id"]`)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using checkpointing to store `since_id` your best option in this case. Here's a diff of what your code should look like, roughly. I've left TODOs for the file IO parts. For the GitHub commits examples in the JavaScript & C# SDKs, we store 1 commit sha per line in the checkpoint file. For your case, you'll only need to store `since_id` in the file. Be mindful of the fact that each instance of your input should have it's own checkpoint file (ie: each input maps to a single hashtag, so you should have 1 checkpoint file for each hashtag you're indexing).

```
diff --git a/program.py b/program.py
index 95f69de..defb535 100644
--- a/program.py
+++ b/program.py
@@ -1,14 +1,17 @@
 def stream_events(self, inputs, ew):
     twitter = OAuth1Session(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

+    checkpoint_dir = inputs.metadata['checkpoint_dir']
+
     for input_name, input_item in inputs.inputs.iteritems():
         hashtag = input_item["hashtag"]
         since_id = input_item["since_id"]

-        if since_id == "0":
-            url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%%23%s" % hashtag
-        else:
-            url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?since_id=%s&q=%%23%s" % (since_id, hashtag)
+        checkpoint_file_path = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, hashtag + ".txt")
+
+        since_id = "" # TODO: read from the file
+        
+        url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?since_id=%s&q=%%23%s" % (since_id, hashtag)

         r = twitter.get(url)

@@ -16,4 +19,6 @@ def stream_events(self, inputs, ew):
         if len(output["statuses"]) != 0:

             for tweet in output["statuses"]:
-                print_xml_stream(input_name, json.dumps(tweet), tweet["created_at"])
\ No newline at end of file
+                print_xml_stream(input_name, json.dumps(tweet), tweet["created_at"])
+
+        # TODO: on success, update the contents of the checkpoint file
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've another short question. Do you have any idea why some tweets are duplicated?

Comment: @BlackSalt are they duplicated by the Twitter API, or in Splunk? Either way, I think the best way to guarantee unique tweets is to store a unique value for each tweet in the checkpoint file. For example, "splunk/status/727553815617114113" but maybe just the number is sufficiently unique. You'd have to read the Twitter API docs to find out for sure